# How to access the Django Model Instance from a Django Field

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a Custom Field that can access it's Django Model to perform some work.  Do Model Fields have this ability?

Here is what I'd like to do, but the code is obviously not complete:

```
from django.db import models

class MyField(models.Field):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # access the Model instance here, and do stuff
        super(MyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = MyField()
```

Comment: If `MyField` inherits from `HandField`, why is that not in the parent-class-list for this class? Just wondering.

Comment: @PeterRowell sorry, that was a copy paste typo when I was trying to make the code more generic for the quesiton. I updated the code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything obvious in the docs.

From looking at the code in `django/db/models/fields/__init__.py` (v 1.9.6), `class Field` has an attribute called `model`, which appears to refer to the parent. I haven't dug any deeper, but that class definition has a lot of stuff happening that may be of interest. Good luck!

Comment: I did the same. Thank you for taking the time to help me.  Looks like `self.model` appears in a couple of methods within `django.db.models.Field`, but in those methods it's not the normal Django Model instance that were used to, and doesn't have access to the other fields.

Comment: Mmm, maybe, maybe not. In `django.db.models.base.py` you will find `class Model`. There are a number of iterations over `self._meta.concrete_fields` which sure looks like what you were describing. At line 625 is `def save(...), and the first thing it does is iterate over that attribute. Play with it, do some pprint()'s.